# Mongrel hangs with 100% CPU / EBADF (Bad file descriptor)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongrel, rmagick

We have a server with 10 running mongrel_cluster instances with apache
in front of them, and every now and then one or some of them hang.
No activity is seen in the database (we're using activerecord sessions).
Mysql with innodb tables. show innodb status shows no locks. show
processlist shows nothing.

The server is linux debian 4.0

Ruby is: ruby 1.8.6 (2008-03-03 patchlevel 114) [i486-linux]

Rails is: Rails 1.1.2 (yes, quite old)

We're using the native mysql connector (gem install mysql)

"strace -p PID" gives the following in a loop for the hung mongrel
process:

```
gettimeofday({1219834026, 235289}, NULL) = 0
select(4, [3], [0], [], {0, 905241})    = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
gettimeofday({1219834026, 235477}, NULL) = 0
select(4, [3], [0], [], {0, 905053})    = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
gettimeofday({1219834026, 235654}, NULL) = 0
select(4, [3], [0], [], {0, 904875})    = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
gettimeofday({1219834026, 235829}, NULL) = 0
select(4, [3], [0], [], {0, 904700})    = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
gettimeofday({1219834026, 236017}, NULL) = 0
select(4, [3], [0], [], {0, 904513})    = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
gettimeofday({1219834026, 236192}, NULL) = 0
select(4, [3], [0], [], {0, 904338})    = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
gettimeofday({1219834026, 236367}, NULL) = 0
...
```

I used lsof and found that the process used 67 file descriptors (lsof -p
PID |wc -l)

Is there any other way I can  debug this, so that I could for example
determine which file descriptor is "bad"?
Any other info or suggestions? Anybody else seen this?

The site is fairly used, but not overly so, load averages usually around
0.3.

---

Some additional info. I installed mongrelproctitle to show what the
hung processes were doing, and it seems they are hanging on a method
that displays images using file_column / images from the database /
rmagick to resize and make the images greyscale.

Not conclusive the
problem is here, but it is a suspicion.
Is there something obviously wrong with the following? The method
displays a static image if the order doesn't contain an image, else the
image resized from the order. The cache stuff is so that the image gets
updated in the browser every time. The image is inserted in the page
with a normal image tag.

code:

```
 def preview_image
    @order = session[:order]
    if @order.image.nil?
      @headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
      @headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, must-revalidate'
      send_data(EMPTY_PIC.to_blob, :filename => "img.jpg", :type =>
"image/jpeg", :disposition => "inline")
       else
      @pic = Image.read(@order.image)[0]
      if (@order.crop)
       @pic.crop!(@order.crop[:x1].to_i, @order.crop[:y1].to_i,
@order.crop[:width].to_i, @order.crop[:height].to_i, true)
      end
      @pic.resize!(103,130)
      @pic = @pic.quantize(256, Magick::GRAYColorspace)
      @headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
      @headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, must-revalidate'
      send_data(@pic.to_blob, :filename => "img.jpg", :type =>
"image/jpeg", :disposition => "inline")
    end
  end
```

Here is the lsof output if anybody can find any problems in it. Don't 
know how it will format in this message...

```
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() ext3 file system /dev/.static/dev
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND     PID    USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE      SIZE     NODE NAME
mongrel_r 11628 username  cwd    DIR        9,2      4096  1870688 
/home/domains/example.com/usernameOrder/releases/20080831121802
mongrel_r 11628 username  rtd    DIR        9,1      4096        2 /
mongrel_r 11628 username  txt    REG        9,1      3564   167172 
/usr/bin/ruby1.8
mongrel_r 11628 username  mem    REG        0,0                  0 
[heap] (stat: No such file or directory)
mongrel_r 11628 username  DEL    REG        0,8           15560245 
/dev/zero
mongrel_r 11628 username  DEL    REG        0,8           15560242 
/dev/zero
mongrel_r 11628 username  DEL    REG        0,8           15560602 
/dev/zero
mongrel_r 11628 username  DEL    REG        0,8           15560601 
/dev/zero
mongrel_r 11628 username  DEL    REG        0,8           15560684 
/dev/zero
mongrel_r 11628 username  DEL    REG        0,8           15560683 
/dev/zero
mongrel_r 11628 username  DEL    REG        0,8           15560685 
/dev/zero
mongrel_r 11628 username  DEL    REG        0,8           15560568 
/dev/zero
mongrel_r 11628 username  DEL    REG        0,8           15560607 
/dev/zero
mongrel_r 11628 username  DEL    REG        0,8           15560569 
/dev/zero
mongrel_r 11628 username  mem    REG        9,1   1933648   456972 
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.15.0.0
mongrel_r 11628 username  DEL    REG        0,8           15442414 
/dev/zero
mongrel_r 11628 username  DEL    REG        0,8           15560546 
/dev/zero
mongrel_r 11628 username  mem    REG        9,1     67408   457393 
/lib/i686/cmov/libresolv-2.7.so
mongrel_r 11628 username  mem    REG        9,1     17884   457386 
/lib/i686/cmov/libnss_dns-2.7.so
mongrel_r 11628 username  DEL    REG        0,8           15560541 
/dev/zero
mongrel_r 11628 username  DEL    REG        0,8           15560246 
/dev/zero
mongrel_r 11628 username  DEL    REG        0,8           15560693 
/dev/zero
mongrel_r 11628 username  DEL    REG        0,8           15560608 
/dev/zero
mongrel_r 11628 username  mem    REG        9,1     25700   164963 
/usr/lib/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
mongrel_r 11628 username  mem    REG        9,1     83708   457384 
/lib/i686/cmov/libnsl-2.7.so
mongrel_r 11628 username  mem    REG        9,1    140602   506903 
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.7/lib/mysql.so
mongrel_r 11628 username  mem    REG        9,1   1282816   180935 
...
mongrel_r 11628 username    1w   REG        9,2    462923  1575329 
/home/domains/example.com/usernameOrder/shared/log/mongrel.8001.log
mongrel_r 11628 username    2w   REG        9,2    462923  1575329 
/home/domains/example.com/usernameOrder/shared/log/mongrel.8001.log
mongrel_r 11628 username    3u  IPv4   15442350                TCP 
localhost:8001 (LISTEN)
mongrel_r 11628 username    4w   REG        9,2 118943548  1575355 
/home/domains/example.com/usernameOrder/shared/log/production.log
mongrel_r 11628 username    5u   REG        9,1    145306   234226 
/tmp/mongrel.11628.0 (deleted)
mongrel_r 11628 username    7u  unix 0xc3c12480           15442417 
socket
mongrel_r 11628 username   11u   REG        9,1        50   234180 
/tmp/CGI.11628.2
mongrel_r 11628 username   12u   REG        9,1     26228   234227 
/tmp/CGI.11628.3
```

I have installed monit to monitor the server. No automatic restarts yet because of the PID file issue, but maybe I will get the newest version which supports deleting stale PID-files.
It would be nice though to actually fix the problem, because somebody will get disconnects etc if the server need to be restarted all the time (~10 times a day)

The mongrel-processes don't take any large amount of memory when this is happening, and the machine isn't even swapping, so it's probably not a memory leak.

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       4152796    4083000      69796          0     616624    2613364
-/+ buffers/cache:     853012    3299784
Swap:      1999992         52    1999940
```

Comment: Which version of Image Magick are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [ImageScience](http://seattlerb.rubyforge.org/ImageScience.html), RMagick is known to leak massive amounts of memory and lock.

Comment: Replacing rmagick isn't really an option for this project. Besides, I can't reproduce this unless its running in production, so the rmagick developers can't help (I tried asking). And there's no memory leak, but locking only (which may be due to something other)

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 6.3 in the book Deploying Rails Applications (A Step by Step Guide) has a good section on installing and configuring the Monitoring utility Monit on Linux and using it to monitor your mongrels. It can restart your mongrels when they fail.

Older versions of Mongrel had trouble re-starting because of a duplicate PID file existing on disk. Newer versions support the --clean option that will get rid of the leftover PID files, if they exist. So you have to upgrade Mongrel to a version that supports --clean to get around the stale PID file issue, Monit alone can't do this.